# How can I replace an applied material with a different one?

Tags: materials

[image]

I applied 'material' to a cube and added 'material.001'. I want the 'material' to be replaced by 'material.001'. I could not find such 'replace' menu in properties editor.

How can I do it?

Comment: Just remove "Material" (click on minus symbol) so that "Material.001" is the only listed material. You only want multiple material slots if you plan on using multiple materials in the same mesh. Edit: Just saw Christopher's comment, and that works as well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With "Material" selected, click the little "globe" next to where it says "material" in white (above "preview"). This is the slot selector. Pick material.001 from here

[image: MatSlot]

Comment: your method is good but it makes 'material' to be replaced by 'material.001' in the material slot. I just want 'material' to be replaced by another on the mesh surface being preserved in material slot.

Comment: Then use Starzars answer? Now I'm a bit confused at what you're trying to do. You can select the second slot and change that to "Material" so now you still have both materials, just switched positions.

Comment: when I used 'slot selector' to be replaced 'material' by 'material.001' , 'material' disappeared  in 'active material index' box. I thought that I lost 'material' forever.

Comment: But now I realized that I still choose 'material' in the slot 1. Thank you for answer.

Comment: No problem. To make sure you don't lose a material that's not being used (materials in slots that aren't assigned to anything will be purged when you close blender), hit the little shield next to the material name - this gives the material a "fake user" and lets blender know that it's still in use.

Comment: thank you for good tip.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be in  ***"Edit mode"*** to create and assign new materials to the "selected mesh".[image]

Comment: Not necessarily. If you only want one material assigned to the object, you just have to create a material slot and new material.

Comment: thank you for good answer. your method is helpful to me.

Comment: @Cultmethod That's your interpretation of the question.Judging from the above comments by 나미손 and his upvote , my answer was clearly what he was looking for.Downvoting helpful answers make no sense.

Comment: @나미손 Always thought that this was what you were looking for .Glad it helped.